# Is it possible to calculate md5 of the file and write file to the disk in the same time?

Tags: go

I write a file uploader with Go. I would like to have md5 of the file as a file name when I save it to the disk.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I save a file this way:

```
reader, _ := r.MultipartReader()
p, _ := reader.NextPart()

f, _ := os.Create("./filename") // here I need md5 as a file name
defer f.Close()

lmt := io.LimitReader(p, maxSize + 1)
written, _ := io.Copy(f, lmt)
if written > maxSize {
    os.Remove(f.Name())
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [io.TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) will probably help you.

Comment: Abstract: Read some bytes, do the calculation regarding md5, write those bytes to file, repeat.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, I need some time to understand the idea of using io.TeeReader

Answer (score 4):

here is an example using io.TeeReader to perform both computation and copy at same time

https://play.golang.org/p/IJJQiaeTOBh

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    var s io.Reader = strings.NewReader("some data")

    // maxSize := 4096
    // s = io.LimitReader(s, maxSize + 1)

    h := sha256.New()
    tr := io.TeeReader(s, h)
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr)
    fmt.Printf("\n%x", h.Sum(nil))

}
// Output:
//some data
//1307990e6ba5ca145eb35e99182a9bec46531bc54ddf656a602c780fa0240dee
```

And the comparison test for correctness

```sh
$ echo -n "some data" | sha256sum -
1307990e6ba5ca145eb35e99182a9bec46531bc54ddf656a602c780fa0240dee  -
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. But as you can can see I use io.LimitReader to validate max file size. Actually I do not understand how to use it with io.TeeReader

Comment: i updated the example code. The Limit reader is to be set onto the source of data so you limit both computations and ends early the processing.

Comment: It is a little bit different logic. In my code if the file is over limit I won't save it (I will delete it). As I can see in your code, if the file is over limit you will save a part of the file. So I use io.LimitReader to save files which are smaller then limit (I have updated my code)

Comment: with a io.LimitReader setup on the source you can **not** have files written on disk larger than `maxSize`. Your logic is wrong. You should stat your files to get their sizes before proceeding further.

Comment: @mn-cbon Ok, Yes, you are right, I see my mistake. So my "if statement" will be always false?

Comment: You have set the limitReader to `maxSize **+ 1**`. You will end up with files chunks written of max(size)=(maxSize + 1). So `written` can **never** be larger than `maxSize`

Comment: Ok, I forgot about it :D Is it possible to change code to work with `reader = r.MultipartReader()` `reader.NextPart()` instead of `strings.NewReader()`? I will accept your answer

Comment: `multipart.Part` implements the standard `io.Reader` interface. https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Part.Read it should be easy to integrate that into your code.

Comment: It doesn't work. What should I place instead `os.Stdout` in this line  `io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr)`? I need to save it to file, but I can't as I do not know it's name

Comment: anything that is an io.Writer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `io.TeeReader` I have used `io.MultiWriter` to create 2 buffers (I will use the first buffer to calculate md5 and the second to write to a file with md5 name)

```
lmt := io.LimitReader(buf, maxSize + 1)

hash := md5.New()

var buf1, buf2 bytes.Buffer
w := io.MultiWriter(&buf1, &buf2)

if _, err := io.Copy(w, lmt); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if _, err := io.Copy(hash, &buf1); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("md5 is: ", hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)))

// Now we can create file with os.Openfile passing md5 name as an argument + write &buf2 to this file
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the solution with TeeReader [here](https://play.golang.org/p/NY4dfXpTHt), but simplified it like this:

```golang
type HashReader struct {
    io.Reader
    hash.Hash
}

func NewHashReader(r io.Reader, h hash.Hash) HashReader {
    return HashReader{io.TeeReader(r, h), h}
}

func NewMD5Reader(r io.Reader) HashReader {
    return NewHashReader(r, md5.New())
}

func main() {
    dataReader := bytes.NewBufferString("Hello, world!")
    hashReader := NewMD5Reader(dataReader)

    resultBytes := make([]byte, dataReader.Len())
    _, err := hashReader.Read(resultBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hashReader.Sum(nil)))
}
```

hex-encoded string of md5 looks more familiar to me, but feel free to encode result byte array of `hashReader.Sum(nil)` as you wish.

P.S. One more thing on the playground example. They assign md5 result on EOF, but definitely not all consumers read until EOF. Since Hash object stores current hash calculation, it is enough to call `hashReader.Sum` after consumption finishes and use the result.